# Ruby: Sorting an array that is "linked" to another array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

In my rails app, I have a loop in my controller that does this:

```
event_prices = []
event_dates = []
for event in @customer.events
  event_prices.push(event.total_prices)
  event_dates.push(event.event_time.strftime("%b %d, %Y at %I%p"))
end
```

I then use the arrays to push data into a highcharts graph. What I want to do is sort the `event_dates` array in order, but if I do that, I'll lose the order of the `event_prices`. Right now, the `event_price[1]` corresponds to `event_dates[1]` and so on, but if I call a `sort!` on `event_dates`, it won't sort `event_prices` along with it.

So how can I get it so that I sort both arrays the same way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like:

```
event_prices = []
event_dates = []
@customer.events.sort_by { |e| e.event_time }.each do |event|
  event_prices << event.total_prices
  event_dates << event.event_time.strftime("%b %d, %Y at %I%p")
end
```

Comment: Wow, you are a ruby wizard :)

Thanks

Comment: Btw this will by default sort them oldest to newest. To get the reverse you could just reverse the list, or alternatively save off the current date `now = Time.now` and then make the block to `sort_by` like so: `now - e.event_time`.

Comment: Thanks again. I actually want oldest to newest, so this is great :)

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you have a problem... just in case I fat-fingered it. Also keep in mind that you can do this through your association (as in `@customer.events(...)` or using named scopes like defining `@customer.ordered_events`) but this might not be a big deal for your use-case. Take a look at the active record association docs.

Comment: For named scope, try starting here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/108-named-scope

Answer (score 4):

It's better to use DB for sorting. I would do the following:

```
event_prices, event_dates = 
  @customer.events(:order => "event_time ASC").map do |e|
    [e.total_prices, e.event_time.strftime("%b %d, %Y at %I%p")]
  end.transpose
```